# Get response logs with response size for Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, unicorn

How can I get the logs for each hit to my rails app with the size of each response?

I get the logs for each api hits and a response log which says "Completed 200 OK in 69.5ms". But I need the size of each response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have nginx by any chance? or use something like or similar

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_action :print_size

  def print_size
    Rails.logger.info "#{controller_name}##{action_name}: #{response.body.size}"
  end
end
```